# Как передать функцию из модели в контроллере laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добавляю в модель `Feed` функцию

```
function getPhrase( $number, $titles ) {
  $cases = array( 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2 );
  return $titles[ ( $number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20 ) ? 2 : $cases[ min( $number % 10, 5 ) ] ];
}
```

Пытаюсь вызвать ее в контроллере FeedController

```
getPhrase( $no, $phrase[ $i ] )
```

В результате получаю

```
"Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\getPhrase()"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же сами пишете, что добавляете в **МОДЕЛЬ** функцию. Значит от экземпляра класса модели (не имени, метод не статический) и вызывайте ее.

Пример:

```
$feed = new Feed();
$feed->getPhrase(params...)
```

А вообще советовал бы Вам не ларавель колупать, а ООП поучить...